# Django CSRF missing in AJAX POST request

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

So I have been integrating AJAX with my Django code, and I followed the instructions at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax. The code worked for a little bit, but I noticed that it didn't work for my production server. Someone on (I believe) a StackOverflow question posted that their code started failing when they cleared their cache, so in the browser tab in which my AJAX code was working, I cleared out the cache and cookies (I really cleaned out everything like you would if you were trying to make your session private) and, lo and behold, the code would not work any more. So somehow the CSRF token is not being transmitted to wherever it needs to be transmitted to. The error that I get is a 403 error.

Comment: You can get a 403 because of a bad token, but also if the `Host` header that Django gets does not match the `Referrer`. This can happen with bad proxy setups (usually with Nginx, but sometimes Apache) and I would probably just confirm that isn't the issue.

Comment: How would I confirm that this is not the issue?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I added a csrfmiddlewaretoken to the data that i posted to solve this issue. It's slightly annoying to have to type this in for every post, but I couldn't figure out why the code on the Django site wasn't working.

Comment: i'm having the same problem, any solution?

Comment: As I said before, I added a "csrfmidlewaretoken" property to the dictionary that is passed by the POST request. It would look like this with the jQuery AJAX shortcut `$.post()`: `$.post("urltopostto", { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' }, function(data) {
  #what to do when post gets back to you
});`

Comment: In my opinion adding the csrfmiddlewaretoken to the dictionary is clearer to the coder because it makes it clear that you have to pass a csrf token every time you post.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF errors are the bane of my existence in Django.
I've found that loading this js works very well for handling these kind of errors. 
The CSRF token lives in your cookies which is why clearing your cookies may have worked for you in the past. 
Load this up before you make the ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unless I mistyped something, I had put this code into my project per the instructions on the Django site, and it didn't work.